# PostMessage(hwnd, WM_SETTEXT,..) does not work while PostMessage(hwnd, WM_QUIT,..) does

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

I have 2 apps,one is hidden window ("hW"), another is console app ("CA"),from 
which i suppose to send commands to hW.
In console app i'm getting hW handle,and here is a question:
if i'm running:

```
PostMessage(hwnd, WM_QUIT, NULL, NULL);
```

everything works fine, message gets to hW and turns it off .But if i'm sending

```
PostMessage(hwnd, WM_SETTEXT, NULL, (LPARAM)"texttext");
```

message does not get to hW at all. Spy++ also shows that message does not get to hW. Is there something specific about WM_SETTEXT , which prevents it? Thanks in advance.

OK. found answer here http://cboard.cprogramming.com/windows-programming/72589-wm_settext-postmessage.html

```
Turns out the API tries to protect me against scope issues; PostMessage() 
always fails with WM_SETTEXT, or any other system-defined message that has
a pointer as a parameter.Which gets me to SendMessage(), which is not good,
because i wanted asynchronous messaging....
```

P.P.S.
Also, looks like

```
SendMessage(hwnd, WM_QUIT, NULL, NULL);
```

does not do anything to target app.Even in simple test app like

```
 HWND hNote;
 if (!(hNote=FindWindow(L"Notepad",NULL)))
        exit(1);
 SendMessage(hNote, WM_QUIT, NULL, NULL);
```

while

```
PostMessage(hNote, WM_QUIT, NULL, NULL);
```

works.
 All that looks so not logical for me... Is there some universal function which works properly with any kind of message?

Comment: I suppose your message is immediately rejected because the pointer you provide is not guaranteed to be valid at dispatch time. You need to work this around using user-defined/registered message where you are responsible for managing the payload string. Or, pass control otherwise into window thread and `SendMessage` from there.

Comment: You need to use SendMessage() here.  And use a Unicode string, usually.

Comment: Thank you. got it now.but wanted to send not predefined text in async message.

Comment: A remark concerning WM_QUIT, you should normally call PostQuitMessage() (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/11/04/489028.aspx)

Comment: patriice has already offered the correct approach to `WM_QUIT`.  The reason `SendMessage` doesn't work is that `SendMessage` calls the window procedure directly, without going through the message loop (`PeekMessage`/`GetMessage` and then `DispatchMessage`).  But `WM_QUIT` is handled in the window loop -- it is special cased by `GetMessage` -- the window procedure has no clue what to do with it.

Comment: Ben, thanks, that explains for me how SendMessage works.

Answer (score 8):

Different messages have different requirements. Some need to be posted to the queue. And some need to be delivered synchronously. So the system is designed to need both delivery mechanisms.

In the case of `WM_SETTEXT`, it always needs to be delivered synchronously. That's because the window manager needs to be able to manage the lifetime of the text data. Raymond Chen talked about this issue: [Why can't I PostMessage the WM_COPYDATA message, but I can SendMessageTimeout it with a tiny timeout?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110916-00/?p=9623)

There is a peril with calling `SendMessage` when the window is in another process. If the other process is hung, that your process will not also become hung. Because `SendMessage` is synchronous.

The solution is to call [`SendMessageTimeout`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644952.aspx). This will marshal your string data into the other process. And you can set a timeout to ensure that, in the eventuality of the other process being hung, your process can avoid that fate.

Comment: And if you really want it to be asynchronous you can always perform the `SendMessageTimeout()` on a thread.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with your last question: no there is not an universal message function that will do what you want.

Let's analyze your cases:

1. `WM_SETTEXT`: That message takes a pointer, so you cannot post it safely between processes, as they will have separated memory addresses, and a pointer from one process would be meaningless to the other. You *can* use `SendMessage()` because Windows knows about the message, copies the data behind the scenes and does the additional hacking. But with `PostMessage()` there is not (cannot be) such magic.
2. `WM_QUIT`: This is a special message that makes message loops break. Making it short, all it does is making `GetMessage` return `FALSE` so the standard message loop(1) finishes. But, ah! that will only work if you `PostMessage()` it. When you `SendMessage()` a message, it is sent directly to the relevant window function, without even stopping in the message queue. And windows do nothing with `WM_QUIT`, because they are simply not expecting it. Actually, even when posted, this message will not reach the window, as the usual loop does not call `DispatchMessage()` for it. That's why it is usually posted to the thread, without window, and so a functions exists that does all that: `PostQuitMessage()`.

(1) Standard message loop:

```
while (GetMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0))
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
```

As a footnote, you can use several tricks to move data between processes:

1. Use `WM_COPYDATA`. AFAIK it cannot be used with `PostMessage()`, but maybe you can create two threads in the target process so that the first one receives the `WM_COPYDATA` and returns quickly, and then posts it to be queued by the second thread.
2. Use shared memory (search for `CreateFileMapping()`) and `PostMessage()` an offset into that memory. You should probably use some `WM_APP + x` user defined message instead of a system one. However, beware of synchronization problems, you will need a mutex or something.
3. Named pipes! (my favourite)
4. Sockets.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is communicate two separated process, regular messages won't work but there is one that could do the trick: the `WM_COPYDATA` message. A related question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451103/use-wm-copydata-to-send-data-between-processes)

Comment: For exactly the same reason that means `PostMessage` cannot be used with `WM_SETTEXT` across a process, neither can it be used to deliver `WM_COPYDATA`. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/09/16/10208976.aspx

Comment: You're right!, I completely forgot about the real issue being sending the message via `PostMessage` instead of `SendMessage`. Your response is the correct one