# How to receive information from a SendMessage() in c++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I got how to [SendMessage to another process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13455475/how-to-send-a-byte-array-to-another-process-in-c). Now I am trying to understand how to receive the message on my other process. I know how to extract my items from de COPYDATASTRUCTURE but what is the method that is called on my other process. I found a lot of stuff on how to read the received data but never how to implement it. So basically, what function/event is called when an application receives a message from SendMessage()? You must know here that I have full control on both process.

Comment: What kind of application are you developing ? Dialog based, MDI, SDI ?

Comment: I am working on a dialog based application using MFC, I explain what it does here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13455475/how-to-send-a-byte-array-to-another-process-in-c

Comment: Have you seen this example ? http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/115/Inter-Process-Communication-using-WM_COPYDATA

Answer (score 0):

The send message from another process is exactly like any send message received from the same process: Specifically the window procedure for the window the message is sent to is called with the message as parameters just as you would receive a WM_PAINT or any other op-sys message.

Comment: So I just have to declare a function like LRESULT CALLBACK MainWndProc(HWND hwnd,UINT uMsg,WPARAM wParam,LPARAM lParam) and that function will be triggered when receiving a message am I right?

Answer (score 0):

Consider reading this blog post, containing sample code:

[Using WM_COPYDATA to marshal message parameters since the window manager otherwise doesn't know how](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/10/19/10360980.aspx)

(You simply handle `WM_COPYDATA` in the receiver `WndProc`.)