# How to cast a LRESULT to a custom struct type?

Tags: c++, winapi, sendmessage, wm-copydata

I use `sendMessage` and `replyMessage` to communicate between two apps in the same laptop. On the receiver side, when it receives the message comes from sender, it will reply with a message. So in the sender process, it will cast the `MyStruct` to LRESULT, send reply this to the sender app. I tried to cast it back in the receiver side, it also works.

```
    PCOPYDATASTRUCT result;
MyStruct* data;
LRESULT a;
MyStruct* t;
MyStruct* reply = new MyStruct;
switch (uMessageType)
{
case WM_COPYDATA:
    result = (PCOPYDATASTRUCT)addtionalData;
    data = (MyStruct*)result->lpData;

    reply->msgId = 10;
    strcpy_s(reply->msgInfo, 100, "test reply");
    a = reinterpret_cast<LRESULT>(reply);
    t = reinterpret_cast<MyStruct*>(a);//when cast the LRESULT data to MyStruct back here, it succeed

    ReplyMessage(reinterpret_cast<LRESULT>(reply));


    break;
```

However, when I was trying to cast this LRESULT to `MyStruct` in the sender side, it fails:

```
LRESULT result = SendMessage(test, WM_COPYDATA, (WPARAM)(HWND)hwndC, (LPARAM)(LPVOID)&data);
MyStruct* reply = (MyStruct*)result;//the value of reply is unreadable
```

How could I convert the LRESULT to my custom struct in the sender side ?

**I just tried to send interger or float by the way. It works. However, if I use custom struct `MyStruct`, it won't work. I guess it is because the size of LRESULT is shorter than `MyStruct`.How to solve this problem ? The size of LRESULT is 4, size of int is also 4.**

```
typedef struct msg{
int msgId;
char msgInfo[100];
}MyStruct;
```

Comment: SendMessage() returns TRUE or FALSE when you use WM_COPYDATA.  Why you think you can treat the return value like a pointer is very hard to guess.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950(v=vs.85).aspx , check this link, it says the return value is LRESULT

Comment: @molbdnilo I know I cannot pass address between app. However, even though I don't use new, use copy constructor, I still cannot cast it successfully. I tried both of them, I only post one of them in this question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use WM\_COPYDATA to send data between processes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451103/use-wm-copydata-to-send-data-between-processes)

Comment: Things won't work for you, if you continue to fail at comprehending documentation. If you think that you don't need to know what you're doing, [using data copy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649009.aspx) comes with a fully working sample implementation. (In case you're wondering, the down vote is due to lack of research.)

Comment: @molbdnilo: While true in general, the OS performs marshaling of data for standard window messages. For example, the pointer passed as *lParam* for [WM_GETTEXT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632627.aspx) is marshaled by the system to end up being meaningful in the target process. [WM_COPYDATA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649011.aspx) being another example, where pointers are marshaled by the system as needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you send `WM_COPYDATA`, the data itself is copied to the receiving process.
The receiver of `WM_COPYDATA` gets a pointer to this copy.
It's very unlikely that the addresses are the same on both ends, but each end has a valid pointer to its own copy of the data.

On the other hand, `ReplyMessage` does no such copying and only returns the (reinterpreted) address of the sender's data.
This is not a valid address on the receiving end.

If you want to pass data back and forth, you need to use `SendMessage` with `WM_COPYDATA` in both directions, possibly adding your own protocol on top.